# Why am I getting different answers for expressions containing x^(1/2) and x^(0.5)?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, syntax, warning-messages

I'm doing a constrained optimization function, where I maximize a function with two arguments subject to a simple constraint:

```
Maximize[4*(x^(1/2) + y^(1/2))^2, 5 x + 4 y == 170, {x, y}]
```

This successfully returns

```
{306, {x -> 136/9, y -> 425/18}}
```

This is great. No problem here. But, when I simply replace the power (1/2) with (0.5), as follows,

```
Maximize[4*(x^(0.5) + y^(0.5))^2, 5 x + 4 y == 170, {x, y}]
```

I get the following errors:

```
    NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -33.8342-10.7215 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {34.6632,-0.829053}. >>
    NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -33.8342-10.7215 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {34.6632,-0.829053}. >>
    NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -33.8342-10.7215 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {34.6632,-0.829053}. >>
    Further output of NMaximize::nrnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

What's the matter here? I'm very new to mathematica and I don't understand if this is a syntax error or a mathematical error. Any ideas most appreciated.

Comment: It appears that using machine precision numbers (e.g., 0.5) causes `Maximize` to invoke `NMaximize`.  Performing `NMaximize[4*(x^(1/2) + y^(1/2))^2, 5 x + 4 y == 170, {x, y}]` gives the same error.

Comment: This works: `Maximize[4*(x^(0.5) + y^(0.5))^2, 
 5 x + 4 y == 170 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]`, although I find it peculiar.

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier comment, `Maximize` definitely calls `NMaximize`, when finite-precision numbers are used.  According to its documentation, `Maximize` excludes function arguments that lead to complex numbers, but the `NMaximize` documentation is silent on this point.  Evidently, `NMaximize` does not exclude arguments that lead to complex numbers, and so it fails when they occur.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html):

> - If `Maximize` is given an expression containing approximate numbers, it automatically calls `NMaximize`.

That the functions `Maximize[]` and `NMaximize[]` have different algorithms is well-documented.